# HTML file upload permission error in safari

Tags: file-upload, safari

The error that gets logged on console is a NOT_READABLE_ERR, which I found is "The file or directory cannot be read, typically due to permission problems that occur after a reference to a file has been acquired (for example, the file or directory is concurrently locked by another application)."

function readFile(myfiles){

          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = loadHandler;

          reader.onerror = errorHandler; 

          reader.readAsText(myfiles[0]);

    }

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. The error in my case was due to an editor locking the file after the user has selected it in the form(Editing the file after form selection). In this case, you could just tell the user to select the file again.

Essentially, the browser loses it's permission to read the file if the user manipulates(edit, save, delete) the file after uploading it.